# Visual Basic overflow error

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a program in Visual Basic and need to find the mean of an array of numbers from a text file. I keep getting an error of "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" in the part of where I use `counter += 1` in my `getNumbers` sub and don't know how to fix it. But I have only learned a very basic form of VB (not that advanced yet).

This is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
   Dim counter As Integer
   Dim num() As Integer
Private Sub btnMean_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMean.Click
   getNumbers()
   lstOutput.Items.Add("The mean is: " & FindMean(num, counter))
End Sub

Sub getNumbers()
   Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
   sr = IO.File.OpenText("digits.txt")
   Do While sr.Peek <> -1
      counter += 1
   Loop
   sr.Close()
   sr = IO.File.OpenText("digits.txt")
   Do While sr.Peek <> -1
     For i As Integer = 0 To counter
       num(i) = CInt(sr.ReadLine)
     Next
   Loop
   sr.Close()
End Sub
Function FindMean(ByRef num() As Integer, ByRef counter As Integer) As Double
   Dim total As Integer = 0
   For k As Integer = 0 To num.GetUpperBound(0)
     total += num(k)
   Next
   Return (total / counter)
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You did nothing in your first `Do While` loop. Shouldn't you at least `ReadLine()` ?

Comment: If i do that i get another error saying: Object reference not set to an instance of an object for the num(i) = CInt(sr.Readline)

Comment: It's because `i` is not defined in first `Do While` loop

Comment: how would I include i in the first Do While so that it doesn't give me that error?

Comment: I think your overflow is in the `FindMean` function. How big are the numbers you are reading in? Specifically `total` as an `integer`. Change it to `Long`

Comment: is there a way too keep the general way i had my code only because I'm not to familiar with the ways you are using

Comment: Just use my replacement. It should be a copy and paste over your class and I have provided more examples of how Linq works. It's also very similar to your original. I'm here to continue working with you to get your code working. Just let me know how I can help by tagging me in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You got an extra loop. Just keep it simple by using `EndOfStream` function.

```
Sub getNumbers()
   Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
   sr = IO.File.OpenText("digits.txt")
   Dim i As Integer = 0
   While Not sr.EndOfStream
       num(i) = CInt(sr.ReadLine())
       i++
   End While
   sr.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I wonder who/why down-voted the correct solution to the question. It seems to be written fine to me. I fixed with an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be that you didn't give counter a default value, but mainly because in your counter loop you never readLine to move to the next line. You only Peek which does not move you through the file. See full solution below for a complete replacement of your code.

Using Linq to find the mean might be easier and a better choice. Read this entire answer to get a better idea of Linq.

```
Dim mean As Double = num.Average()
Dim sum As Long = num.Sum()
```

**Full Solution**
Here is what your code would look like when using Linq. You won't need a `FindMean` function. You should be able to paste this right over yours and get the result you want.

```
Public Class Form1
   Dim num As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
Private Sub btnMean_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMean.Click
   getNumbers()
   lstOutput.Items.Add("The mean is: " & num.Average())
End Sub

Sub getNumbers()
   Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
   sr = IO.File.OpenText("digits.txt")
   Do While sr.Peek <> -1
     num.Add(CInt(sr.ReadLine))
   Loop
   sr.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Another thing you can do with Linq is exclude certain values from your average. Take this example that sets 9 items in `myNumbers()` to 10 and then sets the 10th one to zero. I use Linq to first filter for numbers greater than zero then I perform the `Average` aggregate.

```
Dim myNumbers(9) As Double
For i As Integer = 0 To 8 Step 1
    myNumbers(i) = 10
Next i

myNumbers(9) = 0

Dim average As Double = myNumbers.Where(Function(num) num > 0).Average()
'Optionally, you could also do it this way:
Dim average2 As Double = (From num In myNumbers
                          Where num > 0).Average()
MessageBox.Show(average)
```

It gets even better when you use classes. Consider this class `Thing`:

```
Public Class Thing
 Public Name As String = ""
 Public Number As Double = 0

 Public Sub New (name As String, number As Double)
    Me.Name= name
    Me.Number = number
 End Sub
End Class
```

I can create a collection of that class and the `.Where` becomes even more powerful. In this example I'm averaging `Thing.Number` by `Thing.Name`

```
Dim things As List(Of Thing) = New List(Of Thing)()
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 10))
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 5))
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 7))
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 9))
things.Add(New Thing("Rian", 10))
things.Add(New Thing("Rian", 10))
things.Add(New Thing("Rian", 10))

Dim AverageMichael As Double = things.Where(Function(thing) thing.Name = "Michael").Average(Function(thing) thing.Number)
Dim AverageRian As Double = things.Where(Function(thing) thing.Name = "Rian").Average(Function(thing) thing.Number)

MessageBox.Show(AverageMichael)
MessageBox.Show(AverageRian)
```

Comment: In your full solution, you never initialize the `num` array with a size.  Later, when trying to access the array using `num(i)` you will get an exception.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I fixed that by initializing it as a generic list of Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation for `StreamReader.Peek()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

> Returns the next available character but does not consume it.

So it means that your loop :

```
Do While sr.Peek <> -1
  i += 1
Loop
```

will never end since you are just looking at the first char in the buffer and leaving it there...

**The Solution**

Remove that loop, and place your counter in the second loop.

```
While Not sr.EndOfStream
    num(i) = CInt(sr.ReadLine())
    i++
End While
```